# Swift used Codable, but the type is not correct

Tags: swift, codable, jsondecoder, jsonencoder

I know that Codable = Decodable & Encodable but when calling json from xcode,

Codable was given as a struct, but an error saying

`Argument type'login.Type' does not conform to expected type'Encodable'` appears.

**json code**

```
struct login: Codable {
    var userId: String?
    var userPw: String?
```

```
class func LoginBoard(_ completeHandler: @escaping (login) -> Void) {
            
    let loginboard: String = MAIN_URL + "/member/login"
    guard let url = URL(string: loginboard) else {
      print("Error: cannot create URL")
        return
    }
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    urlRequest.httpBody = try? JSONEncoder().encode(login) // ERROR [Argument type 'login.Type' does not conform to expected type 'Encodable']
            
    let session = URLSession.shared

    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
        print("error calling Post on /todos/1")
         print(error!)
           return
        }

        guard let responseData = data else {
        print("Error: did not receive data")
          return
        }

        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder.init()
            let LoginList = try decoder.decode(login.self, from: responseData)
            completeHandler(LoginList)
        }
        catch {
            print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
            return
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

There is no error in **try decoder.decode**

but only in **urlRequest.httpBody = try? JSONEncoder().encode(login)** what is the problem?

Comment: What `userId` and `userPw` are you trying to encode? You need to encode an instance of `login`, not the type `login`.

Comment: userId and userPw are just api values.

I am trying to log in using the POST method by connecting to the server.

Comment: I know. But *what values* are you trying to POST? Show the JSON that you want to send to the server.

Comment: I just wanted to directly input values ​​in IdTextField and PwTextField and send the input values ​​to the server.

Comment: That's a good example why structs with starting lowercase letter can cause confusion 

Comment: Sorry. I am still a beginner and make a lot of grammar mistakes. Thanks for telling me. I'll fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have something like this to set the values.

```
let loginvalues = login(userId: "john", userPw: "adfadfa")

urlRequest.httpBody = try? JSONEncoder().encode(loginvalues)
```

If you place this inside a play ground and run it you will see that you get the json data.

```
struct Login: Codable {
    var userId: String?
    var userPw: String?
}

let loginvalues = Login(userId: "john", userPw: "adfadfa")

let test = try? JSONEncoder().encode(loginvalues)
print(String(data: test!, encoding: .utf8)!)
```

Comment: Thank you. However, when I change Codable to Encodable in the code, I get an error.
do {
 let decoder = JSONDecoder.init()
 let LoginList = try decoder.decode..
}
add loginvalues
Can I only use it as a Codable? Then there are no errors.

Comment: Sorry I not sure why I did that. You can leave it as `Codable` and it should work for you.